# Using visual studio Code, How do I search for a string like -> MyFunction("

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to visual studio code. I want to type something in to the search box and find exactly that.

If I enter: MyFunction("

I want it to find all of the uses of the function MyFunction. But VSCode complains about the parenthesis not being closed with error "Invalid regular expression ... Unterminated group"

If I search for just my MyFunction, I get hundreds of extra hits in comments, and other places where the keyword is used.

I've tried googling how the search box is used but have not been able to resolve this.

What is the correct way to use the search box for expressions like the one above?

Comment: you can add a backslash to the search `MyFunction\(`

Answer (score 3):

You are searching using Regex rather than string Match.

You can use `Match Whole Word` instead of regular expression. (The middle Icon should be selected)
[image]

Comment: unselect the `.*` button